# JQuery document click unbind removes all children click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, jquery-events

I add a click event to a specific element using JQuery's `live()`:

```
 $('#foo').live('click');
```

Later, I add `bind()` to document:

```
 $(document).bind('click');
```

Once document is clicked, I unbind document click:

```
 $(document).unbind('click');
```

This caused problem: my `#foo` element no longer has a click event because it is document's child. How can I remove document's click leaving `#foo` element untouched?

Here is demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/zS2Mt/2/

Comment: `$(document).unbind('click')` should not remove the click handler for anything but `document`. `#foo` should stay untouched. Something else must be going wrong.

Comment: This is not the case; http://jsfiddle.net/aLnBS/

Comment: Side note: you can use [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) for event handlers that unbind automatically after executing once.

Comment: I just modified my question with more details and corrections. There is also a demo. Sorry but it is live() that is ignored, not bind()

Comment: Try `on` or `delegate` rather than `live`. Maybe it is because `live` attaches delegate event handlers on the document?

Comment: fyi, jsfiddle is down right now apparently :)

Comment: The bind() works also, as indicated above. But live() just no longer works.

Answer (score 5):

You can use events namespaces

[Namespaced Events](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events)

```
$(document).bind('click.documentEvent');

$(document).unbind('click.documentEvent');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach. You could just have two click events and check the target of the click event when clicking on the document and verify that it is not the link. I'm sure there is a better way to do this but it works:

```
var clicked = "I am clicked. Click outside!";
var unclicked = "Click me now!";

$('#foo').click(function() {
   if($(this).html() == unclicked) {
       $(this).html(clicked);
   }      
});

$(document).click(function(e) {
   if(e.target != $('#foo')[0] && $('#foo').html() == clicked) {
       $('#foo').html(unclicked);
   }      
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zS2Mt/3/